# How can I add a file chooser in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Right now, I have a GUI program that allows you to change parameters and stuff like that. I want to make it so you can choose a picture instead of only having one for the whole thing.

I have this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

When I try to use this, it will just say that it cannot import `filedialog`.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I just fixed that error by using:

```
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
```

Now I just need help making the file I choose be the one that appears on the canvas. Right now, I have this:

```
__dir__ = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  
filename = os.path.join(__dir__, root.filename)

img = PIL.Image.open(filename)
shrek= img.resize((100,100))

root = Tk() # create main window; must be done before using ImageTk
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "E:/Images",title =              "choose your file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)
```

I am trying to make the file that I choose from the explorer replace the current file.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message from your IDE

Comment: I actually fixed that error by using `import tkFileDialog as filedialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Python 2.x `import tkFileDialog as filedialog`

I guess you use Python 2.x..

Comment: sorry I only use this at school